# Ajax timed update issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, setinterval

Simply I have a menu bar with an animated notification badge made by CSS and implemented by SPAN class on the HTML. this badge should show the count of new messages and disappear if that count is 0. I need to check that every 1 second but with no luck.

my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeAnimation(){
setTimeout(function() {
$('.bubble').removeClass('animating')
}, 200);            
}

setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:  'models/bubble.php',
    data: 'html',
    success: function(response){
    document.getElementById("bub").innerHTML=response;
    document.getElementById("bub").className = "bubble";
    }
    error: function(response) {
    document.getElementById("bub").className = "hidden";
    });
}
}, 1000);
</script>
```

my php (working and tested):

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
$receiver = $this_user
$isnew = 1;
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM messenger
    WHERE receiver = ? AND isnew = ? ORDER BY timestamp")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $receiver,$isnew);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $ttlrows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
}
echo $ttlrows;
?>
```

any help?

Comment: it doesn't read the php output, in older versions of my code it was reading the output only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below works for me. You need to call the function inside success again as setTimeout/setInterval will call the function only once after the delay you mentioned

```
setTimeout('pullNewMessageCount()', 100);


 function pullNewMessageCount() {
  var url = 'PHP Url';
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data:{
      "whatever data you want to send, skip it if not require",
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(latestCount) {
      setTimeout('pullNewMessageCount()', 100);// Important comment (this what you need to do)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: ok, but you missed the part of updating the content of my span with id (bub) to show the badge with the right count, and also I want to hide that same span by assigning the class (hidden) if the count is 0. it's kinda like facebook notification system, the span of the bubble id is (bub) and the bubble animated class is (.animating) and the hidden class is (.hidden)